# How do I print a hex value?

Tags: python

the following code:

```
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long='\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x0A\x21\x1C', command=mycommand, frame_id='\x01')
response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
print(response)
```

returns this response:

```
{'status': '\x00', 'source_addr': '\x8b>', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n!\x1c', 'frame_id': '\x01', 'command': 'D0', 'parameter': '\x04', 'id': 'remote_at_response'}
```

from the response, I can get myid quite easily, I just type:

```
 myid = response['id']
print myid
```

Now I want to get the parameter and store it as myparameter, but it is hex so 
`myparameter = response['parameter']` does not work.

How can I get the hex parameter `\x04` and simply print it?

Comment: Does the [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function do what you want?

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: the expected output is \x04 or even 04

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to print `response['parameter']`, but you want to see `\x04` (literally)? If so, you can use `print repr(response['parameter'])[1:-1]`

Comment: Thank you @Rufflewind. ord worked perfectly.          myhexparameter = response['parameter']
print ord (myhexparameter) printed 4. That's perfect. Thanks

Comment: @itzzitzz: Keep in mind that `ord` extracts the *numeric value*, which means if you truly want a hex representation, use `hex` in conjunction with `ord`.  (You can also use `repr`, which serves a different purpose but it may suffice for your purposes.)

Comment: Thank you @Rawing, your solution gave me exactly \x04. That's even better

Comment: @Rawing: consider posting your solution as an answer since it solves the OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
print( repr(response['parameter'])[1:-1] )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you confused yourself with your question. The actual question is "how to extract the numeric value of a byte from a byte string", for which the answer is simply `ord()`. Note though that `ord()` only takes a single byte, i.e. a byte string of length one, which I'm not sure if that is guaranteed. Also, in Python 2, strings are byte strings by default, while in Python 3 it requires an explicit 'b' prefix.

Now, coming back to the hex value, the point is that there is no hex involved, except when either writing the response to the console (the `repr()` function is used there) or when writing it in code! Another important thing is that there is no such thing as a "hex value", there is a numeric value and there is a representation of that value using the hexadecimal format. That's why `0x11 == 0b10001 == 17`, because these are value comparisons and the different number bases are just different ways to write the same values.